# JSONP not firing success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Below is a simple Ajax call I'm making to a different domain:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url?callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
                    alert(data[0].DeviceName);   //Just to display
                }
            })
        },
    })
</script>
```

My success function is never fired but a valid JSON is returned on Fiddler.

[image]

Raw Output:

[image]

How can I then display the returned results in my success function?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you implement the server side? Can you please post the RAW answer from the server?

Comment: `valid JSON`. For jsonp it should be not JSON returned.

Comment: @AdrianSalazar Raw output added. By implement server side do you mean using CORS? If so, I'm avoiding using it because of some complications I came across.

Comment: @KevinB Please advise how to return JSON

Comment: I assume you mean JSONP? it has to be done using server-side code, which you haven't provided yet.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, or should I say `return the data as it is on Fiddler`.

Comment: ... As it is on fiddler it is JSON, not JSONP, and you can't use JSON with JSONP

Comment: @Dumisani I put an example of JSONP. So you can mimic the same in your server.

Answer (score 0):

The server returns JSON data, not JSONP as you're expecting.

This could be because you've specified a funky `callback` parameter. Try changing:

```
url: 'url?callback=?'
```

To just `'url'` or whatever it should be but **without the callback parameter**. I'm pretty sure that jQuery will supply a callback parameter for you.

If that doesn't work, then the server is probably unable to return JSON-P data. But apparently it supports plain JSON. So you could maybe just change your call so that you accept JSON data instead:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

FYI: JSON-P is actually a snippet of JavaScript code that invokes a callback function in the browser supplying JSON data as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is that the server is not returning *valid* "JSONP". I'll explain with an example.

The server needs to know two things:

1. When to return JSONP
2. What is the name of the JSONP callback to use.

In the following call to the facebook graph API I am telling facebook the two things mentioned before, in the two parameters "format" and "callback"

http://graph.facebook.com/adrian.salazar.cs?format=JSONP&callback=mything

Facebook will then, give me a valid JSONP response.

```
 /**/ mything({
   "id": "714291966",
   "first_name": "Adrian",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "Salazar",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/adrian.salazar.cs",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "Adrian Salazar",
   "username": "adrian.salazar.cs"
});
```

But, **what the hell is a valid JSOP response?**

Assuming that the server expects you to specify the jsonp callback as a parameter named "jpcallback"

Then your server **must** wrap the normal JSON response using the parameter passed in the jpcallback, as a function call...

So the raw answer for GET http://myserver.com/getdevices?jpcallback=randomJsonpCallback  in JSONP format is:

```
randomJsonpCallback([{ Id: 222, Name: 'aaa' }, { Id: 333, Name: 'bbb' }])
```